# substitute multiple substrings in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to substitute multiple substrings in a value on a visualforce page. I tried using nested SUBSTITUTE() functions, but I get an error message "The element type "p" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "

"."

```
<p class="product-name">
    {!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(p.Product2.Short_Product_Description__c, "{", "<sup>"),"}", "</sup>")}
</p>
```

Note: I am able to do a single substring substitution with a single SUBSTITUTE() call like so:

```
<p class="product-name">
    {!SUBSTITUTE(p.Product2.Short_Product_Description__c, "{", "<sup>")}
</p>
```

However this is undesirable as I also need to substitute the "}" character with a "`</sup>`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found that works:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!
    SUBSTITUTE(
        SUBSTITUTE(p.Product2.Short_Product_Description__c, '[', '<sup>'),
        ']', '</sup>'
    )
}" escape="false"/>
```

The curly braces are what was triggering it and an  with escape attribute set to false is required to render the html properly

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions like your first example. Though I think your problem is elsewhere - there must be another piece of unescaped HTML in your string which is conflicting with the parent `<p>` tag. I strongly suggest using `HTMLENCODE` in conjunction when you're outputting text which may contain HTML code:

`{!HTMLENCODE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(p.Product2.Short_Product_Description__c, "{", "<sup>"), "}", "</sup>"))}`

Comment: Hi Boris, there is no HTML in the string whatsoever. It contains only alphanumeric characters and one instance of "{" and "}", respectively. The error does not occur with the single SUBSTITUTE() call. I tried wrapping the entire thing in HTMLENCODE() as you suggested and still get the error

Comment: Here is a pastebin showing what code triggers and doesn't trigger the error https://pastebin.com/9dVJnUf7

Comment: I just did another test, and I noticed that if I replace the "<sup>" and "</sup"> with "test" and "test2" the nested SUBSTITUTE works.

Comment: I've figured out a solution. It seems the curly braces are what is triggering it. If I replace them with square brackets the nested function works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like with or without HTMLENCODE(), my tags are not rendered properly in the VF page. They appear either as plain text or as "&lt;" and "&gt;". Guess its back to the drawing board...

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it out!

Comment: It looks like if I insert this entire formula into an <apex:outPutText> value attribute and set the escape attribute to "false" I can render the HTML correctly

Comment: Post it as an answer :)